# Linux - How to count occurrences of character 'i' in a word (not a file)

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I print the number of occurrences of "i" in *Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis*?

How can I approach this with the commands [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and [wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
echo "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" | grep -o i | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```sh
echo "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"|tr -cd 'i'| wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" | awk '{print gsub(/i/,"")}'
6
```